# Hashing with separate chaining

Tags: c++, list, hashtable, chaining

Let's consider that for two different inputs(`"tomas"`, `"peter"`) a hash function yields the same key (3). 
Please correct my assumtion how it works under the hood with the separate chaining:
In a hash table, index 3 contains a pointer to a linked list header. The list contains two nodes implemented for example like this:

```
struct node{
    char value_name[];
    int value;
    node* ptr_to_next_node;
};
```

The searching mechanism remembers the input name (`"peter"`) and compares `value_name` in nodes. When it equals with `"peter"`, the mechanism would return the value.

Is this correct? I've learned that ordinary linked list doesn't contain the name of the node so that I didn't know, how could I find the correspondind value in the list with nodes like this for different names (`"tomas"`, `"peter"`):

```
struct node{
    int value;
    node* ptr_to_next_node;
};
```

Comment: Make your life easier and use `std::string value_name;` instead of a raw char array.

Comment: "I've learned that ordinary linked list doesn't contain the name of the node" A list node can contain whatever data you need.

Comment: I think the confusion is coming from difference between hash set and hash map. Hash map stores key and value, hash set stores the value that is its own key.

Comment: Arkadiy: I didn't know neither about hash_map nor hash_set. The confusion arose from: 1) list contains pointer(s) and a value 2) when hash table comes to a collision, it points to a list. => the question is, how can the mechanism find the proper value, when list nodes dont contain the "name" ?

Comment: in your case the value is the "name"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its correct that this is a possible implementation of part of a hash table.

When you say an "ordinary linked list doesn't contain the name of the node", I'd be expecting a linked list to be generic if the implementation language allows that. In C++ it would be a template.

It would be a linked list of a certain type and each element would have an instance of or a handle to that type and a pointer to the next element as your second code snippet shows except substituting int with the type.

In this case the type would most likely be a key-value-pair
So the linked list in that case doesn't directly contain the name - it contains an object that contains the name (and the value)

This is just a possible implementation though. There are other options

Comment: I considered STL list as an ordinary list and thought that it contains one or two pointers and the value. 
In my example with hash table, I missed a string in that "ordinary list" and therefore I was confused how can the mechanism find the correct value among unnamed nodes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, basically: a table of structures, with the hash function limited to return a value between 0 and table size - 1, and that is used as an index into the table.

This gets you to the top of the list of chained elements, which will be greater than or equal to zero in number.

To save time and space, usually the table element is itself a chain list element.  Since you specified strings as the data being stored in the hash table, usually the structure would be more like:

```
struct hash_table_element {
    unsigned int length;
    char *data_string;
    struct hash_table_element *next;
}
```

and the string space allocated dynamically, maybe with one of the standard library functions.  There are a number of ways to manage string tables that may optimize your particular use case, of course, and checking the length first can often times speed up the search if you use short cut evaluation:

```
if (length == element->length &&
    memcmp(string, element->data_string, length))
{
    found = TRUE
};
```

This will not waste time comparing the strings unless they are the same length.